# JupyterLab + Reveal.JS → How to hide code cells?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, reveal.js

I would like to know how to hide the code cells in my notebook when exporting to Reveal.JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with a cell that is a slide, e.g.

[image]

I) Add a tag using "Property Inspector":

```
# In JupyterLab → Property Inspector → Cell Metadata
{
    "tags": [
        "remove-input"
    ]
}
```

[image]

II) convert to slides manually using nbconvert, specifying a pre-processor that will remove inputs in cells with given tag, e.g.:

```
jupyter nbconvert Presentation.ipynb --to slides --no-prompt --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags={\"remove-input\"} --post serve --SlidesExporter.reveal_theme=simple
```

[image: result]

The output html file will be in `Presentation.slides.html`.

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4100#issuecomment-370938358).