# Is there a way of converting jupyter notebook to slides without codes?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

My goal is to create a presentation with Jupyter notebook without code input.

I have tried the following code

```
!jupyter nbconvert Explanatory_Analysis.ipynb --to slides --post serve --no-input --no-prompt
```

This code is prompting the `NotImplementedError`

Comment: What is the actual errors you see listed? You just include 'NotImplementedError' upshot when you want to share the actual traceback as text, like [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4526#issue-426293089). What type of system are you trying to do this on?  What version of the JupyterLab or classic Jupyter notebook interface? Your title question already has answers, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636291/8508004) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67686589/8508004) & probably other places I didn't quickly find. So you want to post a question that gets at your issue.

Comment: Good day @Wayne, I appreciate your kind response, pls pardon my lack of details in my question. This was my first question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat hacky solution.

Paste the following code into a *new* code cell, then execute the cell.

Be sure to change the `NOTEBOOK` variable to the filename of the current notebook and **SAVE** the notebook *BEFORE* running.

The hackiest thing about it is that the code overwrites the current notebook, so you'll need to refresh the juptyer page in your browser after running the script.

```py
import nbformat as nbf
import os

NOTEBOOK = "Explanatory_Analysis.ipynb"
PATH = f'{os.path.abspath("")}/{NOTEBOOK}'
ntbk = nbf.read(PATH, nbf.NO_CONVERT)

for i, cell in enumerate(ntbk.cells):
    if cell.cell_type == "code":
        metadata = cell["metadata"]
        slideshow = metadata.get("slideshow", {})
        print(f"[cell@index={i}] {cell.cell_type=}")
        print(f"BEFORE {metadata=}, {slideshow=}")
        slideshow["slide_type"] = "skip"
        metadata["slideshow"] = slideshow
        print(f"AFTER {metadata=}, {slideshow=}")

nbf.write(ntbk, PATH)
```

Comment: Learning a bit more from  [this article](https://blog.jupyter.org/looking-at-notebooks-from-a-new-perspective-bfd06797f188), there is a relatively new option **dejavu** which by default hides the code. You can try out `jupyter dejavu Explanatory_Analysis.ipynb` and see if that gets you results that you like.